# Retrieving data from Firebase and repeating it in an Angular Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

since I am new to the new SDK of Firebase (I have used a little bit of angularfire) I wanted to retrieve data and with angular to display it.

Here is what  I have done so far:

```
var app = angular.module('dApp',[]);
app.controller('listingControler',['$scope', function($scope){
$scope.downloads = [];


var config = {
    //removed config
 };

  firebase.initializeApp(config);


    var leadsRef = database.ref('/');
    leadsRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {


        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        $scope.downloads.push(childSnapshot.val());



        });
        return  $scope.downloads;
    }); 

  }]);
```

View

```
<body ng-app="dApp">
 <div ng-controller="listingControler">

<ul>
        <li ng-repeat="d in downloads">{{d.email}}</li>
</ul>
</body>
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code above? Can you provide any errors your experiencing?

Comment: see what it prints  console.log($scope.downloads) before return statement.

if It is array, it will work with ng-repeat

Comment: @MohsinPatel sorry i forgot to add that. When I console log it it shows [], but when I open it I can see Objects and the data in them.

Comment: This happens because of asynchronous execution.

snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
     console.log(childSnapshot.email);
        $scope.downloads.push(childSnapshot.val());
});

if it printing what you want it will iterate with ng-repeat only.

Comment: There is no `AngularFire` here.

Comment: @theblindprophet sorry I have missed the word 'before' as  (I have used a little bit of angularfire before)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments you are getting the data (you said console allows you to view object properties).  You need to specify the property names to get the string data.  `snapshot.val().firstName`, for example.